# Confusion with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, distance, google-sheets-api

I'm new to JavaScript and although I have looked at many forums/tutorials I'm struggling with exactly what I need to change to achieve what I want.

I currently have a Google spreadsheet that is populated with UK post codes, these postcodes are automatically added at various points using a combination of google forms and Microsoft forms/flow.

**What I want to do is to automatically calculate the distance in miles between 2 post codes that are in each row**.

For example, in column C there would be a pickup post code, and in column D there would be a Drop off post code - in column E I would like the mileage to automatically display when a new row with new post codes is added.

Currently, I am using the below customer function to calculate the distance in miles, but I need to be able to wrap it in the `ARRAYFORMULA` function in google sheets but when I do only the first cell displays the correct mileage (the others remain blank)

The code below seems to work very well I just can't figure out how to be able to allow the `GOOGLEDISTANCE` function to accept an array of Pick up post codes and an array of drop off post codes and then return an array of the calculated mileage in miles.

Code:

```js
function GOOGLEDISTANCE(pick_up,drop_off,return_type) {
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
      var travelMode = Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.BICYCLING;  
      var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
      .setRegion('UK')
      .setLanguage('en-GB')
      .setOrigin(pick_up)
      .setDestination(drop_off)
      // .addWaypoint(waypoint1)
      .setMode(travelMode)
      .getDirections();

      if (directions.status !== "OK") 
      return "Error: " + directions.status;

     var route = directions.routes[0].legs[0];
     var time = route.duration.value;
     var distance = route.distance.value;

     var steps = route.steps.map(function(step) {
      return step.html_instructions.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
     }).join("\n");

     switch(return_type) {
      case "MILES":
      case "miles":
      return distance * 0.000621371;
      break;
      case "KILOMETERS":
      case "kilometers":
      return distance / 1000;
      break;
      case "MINUTES":
      case "minutes":
      return time / 60;
      break;
      case "HOURS":
      case "hours":
      return time / 60 / 60;
      break;
      case "STEPS":
      case "steps":
      return steps;
      break;
      default:
      // Default to miles
     return distance * 0.000621371;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Found similar question but it is in different community](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125835/how-to-use-custom-function-with-arrayformula)

Comment: If you need to calculate the distance between two locations, why would you need an array formula?

Answer (score 1):

[According to docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) it should have similar structure to code below.

```js
=arrayFormula(GOOGLEDISTANCE_WRAPPER())

function GOOGLEDISTANCE_WRAPPER(data) {
  if(Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(GOOGLEDISTANCE)
  }

  return GOOGLEDISTANCE(data);
}

function GOOGLEDISTANCE(pick_up, drop_off, return_type) {
  ...code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that does allow me to enter arrays and for   the entire column to be calculated, the only thing is now the calculations are incorrect (before they were correct) not sure whats going on there but its one step closer - thank you!

Comment: It is probably because of the data type for each item in array.`GOOGLEDISTANCE(pick_up, drop_off, return_type)` should be changed to `GOOGLEDISTANCE(obj)` and destruct data from `obj` param